# IndexOutOfRangeException with Regex system

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I'm trying to make a Reddit Formatter tool for whenever you have a text with just one line break to add another and make a new paragraph. Here in StackOverflow it's the same, you have to press the enter key twice to start a new paragraph. It'd go from:

```
 Roses are red
 Violets are Blue
```

to

```
 Roses are red

 Violets are Blue
```

It's great, but I don't want to add more than one enter character if it's already a double. I don't want to go from

```
 Roses are red

 Violets are Blue
```

to

```
 Roses are red


 Violets are Blue
```

because it's already working as the first example. It just adds more lines infinitely if you keep pressing the button.

I've tried with this, with the help of someone in this forum:

```
        for (int i = textBox1.Text.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text[i] == '\u000A')//if finds a SINGLE new line
            {
                    textBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(textBox1.Text, "(?:\r\n)+", "\r\n\r\n");
                }
            } 
        }
```

And it works flawlessly... until you enter more than 5 enter keys in a row. Then it crashes with a System.IndexOutOfRangeException. I'm sure the error is from the regex method, though it throws the error in the line where the if statement starts

What happens? I don't get what's going on

Thank you very much

Comment: textBox1.Text is being replaced each iteration, yet the index was based off the initial value. I recommend isolating this code  in order to write a unit test. Then create a failing unit test with the case you mentioned above, in addition to other tests. Then simply fix the code to make the test pass.

Comment: why did you delete your last question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm sure the error is from the regex method,
>    though it throws the error in the line where the if statement starts

The error is thrown because you are trying to access a position which does not exist. `i` has a value that is larger then the amount of elements in the string `textBox1.Text`. The reason that this happens is because you change the string ith this line:

```
textBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(textBox1.Text, "(?:\r\n)+", "\r\n\r\n");
```

`Replace` returns a new string which is assigned to `textBox1.Text`. In this line a multitude of `\r\n` is replaced by only 2 occurences. Your string (in the case of **more than 5 enter keys in a row**) is cut down in length, so that the next iteration of the for loop the variable `i` is larger than the number of chars in your string.

Since `Regex.Replace` will search the entire string that you pass into it, the loop and the if- clause are not necessary. You can simply use this line, and it will always put 2 occurences of `\r\n` into the string if it finds a match. You do the match basically twice, once in the if-clause and once in the `RegEx` call.

Comment: Woah thank you very much, I was using it as a simple replace function and now that I've removed the loop it works perfectly :) Thanks for the clear explanation!